# Laravel call method on any artisan command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to set a method that changes a value in my database automatically when I run a php artisan command? What I'm trying to accomplish is change the value of the first row in my "domains" table to suit the url from my .env file automatically whenever I push codes to my live/staging environment. Are there any ways to do this automatically without me manually going into my DB and changing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a Listener for the native event **CommandFinished** and check if the command is the **config:cache**.

```
Event::listen('Illuminate\Console\Events\CommandFinished', function ($event) {
    if ($event->command == 'config:cache') {
        // Change domains table data using Eloquent or Query Builder
    }
});
```

To learn more about Events, see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#generating-events-and-listeners

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Let me check and see if it works, cheers! :)

Comment: how do i test this thought? I've coded this out, but it does not seem to work; 
`Event::listen('Illuminate\Console\Events\CommandFinished', function ($event) {
            if ($event->command == 'config:cache') {
                
                $url = \Config::get('constants.APP_URL');
                $domain = \App\Domain::where('id', 2)->update(array('url' => $url));

            }
        });`